# How do I delete a CNAME record from Route53 with the Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I see that I need to use the change_resource_record_sets method. But what parameters do I provide? Anyone has an example?

```
route53.change_resource_record_sets(
  { 
    hosted_zone_id: "/hostedzone/EXAMPLEID",
    change_batch: { 
      changes: [ 
        { 
          action: "DELETE", 
          resource_record_set: { 
            name: "r9i.staging.example.com.", 
            type: "CNAME", 
            resource_records: [ 
              { value: "other.example.io" } 
            ], 
            alias_target: nil 
          } 
        } 
      ] 
    }
  })
```

Returns:

```
Aws::Route53::Errors::InvalidInput: Invalid request
from /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-
2.2.3/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in 
`call'
from /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-
2.2.3/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:20:in `call'
from /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-
2.2.3/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
from /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-
```

2.2.3/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
from /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-
2.2.3/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in`block (2 levels) in
    define_operation_methods'
        from (irb):62

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like are are missing the TTL.  Below worked for me.  Replace the TTL value with the value of your record.

```
require 'aws-sdk'
r53 = Aws::Route53::Client.new(region:'us-east-1')


r53.change_resource_record_sets(
  { 
hosted_zone_id: "/hostedzone/ZZZZZ",
change_batch: { 
  changes: [ 
    { 
      action: "DELETE", 
      resource_record_set: { 
        name: "r9i.staging.example.com.", 
        type: "CNAME", 
        ttl: 300,
        resource_records: [ 
          { value: "other.example.io" } 
        ], 
        alias_target: nil 
      } 
    } 
  ] 
}
})
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. It's missing in the developers guide. I'll tell them.